# Error when trying to compile scripts C++ - Unreal Engine 5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

When I try to compile scripts I get these errors and I don't know how to solve them. Does anyone know how to solve them?
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDWYl.png)

Error 1:

```
Expecting to find a type to be declared in a module rules named 'RD' in UE5Rules, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.  This type must derive from the 'ModuleRules' type defined by Unreal Build Tool.
```

Error 2:

```
    <Exec Command="$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)" Condition="'$(NMakeUseOemCodePage)' == 'true' and '$(NMakeBuildCommandLine)'!=''"/>
```

Comment: I would recommend the Unreal forums. There are many more people with Unreal knowledge there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem, in my case I use Rider from Jetbrains as IDE, and when I asked to install the **RiderLink plugin** I installed it in the Engine, and not in the project, and as it is still in early access, Rider is also having some bugs and when I install this plugin in the Engine, it returns these errors.

Comment: Even after removing the plugin I still get this error in Visual Studio.